# Vue.js - Data Property isn't accessible

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js 3 app. In this app, I'm trying to search through an array of object. I've created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fs3ry2qw/). In this fiddle, the code causing the issue looks like this:

```
async runSearch() {
  let searchResults = this.data;
  if (this.searchQuery) {
    let info = JSON.stringify(searchIndex);
    alert(info);
    console.log(searchIndex);
    searchResults = await courseIndex.search(courses);
  }
  this.results = searchResults;
}
```

For some reason, it's like `searchIndex` doesn't exist. However, I do have it in the model as shown here:

```
  data() {
    return {
      searchIndex: null,
      searchQuery: null,      
      data: data,
      results: null,
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I execute a search?

Comment: Try using `this.searchIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `this.searchIndex` to access reactive variables defined in data in Vue.